# I have https on my page but Chrome says it is not secure

Tags: google-chrome, https

I have https on my page but Chrome says it is not secure. I dont understand what is wrong. Look at the screenshot.

[image: e]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are loading an image over HTTP and so the content is mixed causing the warning.

The image in question is `dark-grey-tile.png` it's coming from `http://plugins.jquery.com/jquery-wp-content/themes/jquery/images/dark-grey-tile.png` note the http here - not https

Comment: Yes thats it. Thank you.